# Replace mapValues for ListMap

Tags: scala, dictionary

Scala [immutable Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.ListMap) has a member `mapValues`, which allows to perform mapping on values only (not keys). When using [immutable ListMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.ListMap) instead, this member is inherited, however it is not overridden, therefore it still returns a `Map`, not `ListMap`.

Is there some simple way how to implement `mapValues` for a `ListMap`?

In the following fragment, I want the return type to be a `ListMap`, not `Map`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val lm = ListMap(1 -> "1", 0 -> "0", 2 -> "2")

lm.mapValues ( v => v+v )
```

Comment: Just FYI, this happens because `mapValues`, unlike `map` and other generic combinators, returns a *view* to the existing map and not a new collection. You need to materialize this view, but there seem to be no easier way than either reimplementation of `mapValues` via `map` or appending values to a new map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def listMapValues[K,V1,V2](lm:ListMap[K,V1], f: V1 => V2) = lm.map { case (k,v1) => (k,f(v1))}
```

You can then use it like:

```
scala> listMapValues(lm, v => v + v)
res16: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 11, 0 -> 00, 2 -> 22)
```

If you want to use it as infix method, just need to declare it an implicit class:

```
 implicit class ListMapOps[K,V1](lm: ListMap[K,V1]) { 
    def listMapValues[V2](f: V1 => V2)= lm.map { case (k,v1) => (k,f(v1))}
  }


scala> lm.listMapValues( v => v + v )
res17: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 11, 0 -> 00, 2 -> 22)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.

```
ListMap[Int, String]().empty ++ lm.mapValues(v => v + v)
```

Your code :

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
  val lm: ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap(1 -> "1", 0 -> "0", 2 -> "2")
  val result: ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap[Int, String]().empty ++ lm.mapValues(v => v + v)
```

Output at REPL :

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
lm: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 1, 0 -> 0, 2 -> 2)
result: scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 11, 0 -> 00, 2 -> 22)
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee `lm.mapValues` and `++` with `Map` will maintain the order? Where does the guarantee come from?

Comment: yes, because it only appends the computed map to an empty ListMap.

Comment: @curious, but the computed `Map` may have already lost order, since it's not a `ListMap`

Comment: @Chirlo No, mapValues function will not change the order as it is mentioned in the docs it transforms the original map rather than returning the new map with the given function applied to all its value elements.